# Maximum Likelihood when estimator when data are conditionally independent

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I want to maximize the logrithm of
\begin{align*}
 L(\theta) = f(X|\theta) = \int \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|y,\theta)g(y)\,dy,
\end{align*}
where $X = (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $y$ is missing data. The issue is that, in the model I am working on, $$\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|y,\theta)$$
becomes zero on computer program (Matlab/Python) as $0<f(x_i|y,\theta)<1$ for all $i$ and $y$. Is there any method to deal with this issue?

Comment: Why do x and y have the same index in the likelihood?

Comment: @ping Sorry my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: So, there's a single, global $y$, not an individual $y_i$ for each $x_i$ (as there would be in latent variable models)?

Comment: @user20160 yes there is a single $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can factor out powers of 2 or 10 and count them up separately. That is, instead of

$$L(\theta)=\int\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|y,\theta)g(y)\,dy$$
work with, say,
$$L(\theta)=10^{-an}\int\prod_{i=1}^n 10^af(x_i|y,\theta)g(y)\,dy$$
where the exponent is chosen to keep $f(x_i|y,\theta)$ a reasonable size. Then
$$\log L(\theta)=-2n\log 10 +\log \int\prod_{i=1}^n 10^2f(x_i|y,\theta)g(y)\,dy$$
and you could even forget the first term, since it doesn't depend on $\theta$.